# LGPL v3.0 and how it relates to wkhtmltopdf in a SAAS scenario: what are our obligations?

Tags: lgpl, law

We would like to use this library https://github.com/SebastiaanKlippert/go-wkhtmltopdf to generate PDFs from HTML. That library is licensed under MIT. It is really nothing more than a wrapper for the go language to use this library: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf. wkhtmltopdf is licensed under GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0 (LGPL).

We would like to build and host a docker containerized deployment of a go binary and the wkhtmltopdf lib binary as a microservice in AWS. Internally we would call this service from any number of other microservices when we need to create PDFs. We would not be making any modifications to the library itself, we would only be linking to it dynamically via the go library.

I'm trying to understand what the legal requirements are in a situation like this. Again, we are not modifying the library, nor are we distributing the code or the binary. It's only being used internally and will not be publicly accessible.

Can anyone provide some insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements for the MIT wrapper are simply "don't remove the copyright and license texts".

The requirements for the LGPL library are

- If/when you make changes to the library, effectively distribute them under the LGPL.
- If/when you use the library in an application, give the recipients of the binary the means to replace the library with a version of their own.

All of this only starts to matter when you distribute your software to a third party and putting it on an AWS instance whose contents you control does not count as distribution.
As long as you don't distribute, there are no restrictions coming from the licenses.